# ニフティクラウドmobile backend(NCMB)を使いUnity からAndroidへ書き出すとエラー

Tags: android, unity3d

Unity にて
ニフティクラウドmobile backend(NCMB)を導入した後に、APKファイルに書き出すとエラーがでてAPKをインストールできなくなりました。

Unity上の再生では問題なく動作しています。
Build adn Run を選択すると次の2件のエラーがでます

明確な解決手段ではなくても、このアタリが怪しい、良くあるミス　などを指摘頂けると助かります。

------------1つ目

```
Installation failed with the following output:
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Package.apk

Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]

4242 KB/s (34974957 bytes in 8.051s)

UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

------------２つ目

```
UnityException: Unable to install APK!
Installation failed. See the Console for details.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.ShowErrDlgAndThrow (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.ShowErrDlgAndThrow (System.String title, System.String message)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.UploadAndStartPlayer (System.String manifestName, System.String stagingArea, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDevice device, System.String packageName, Boolean developmentPlayer, Boolean retryUpload)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcessInternal (System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:316)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Comment: やってみた対応
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728725/cant-use-google-play-services-on-unity-java-plugin
を参考に、　をUnity 内のversion.xmlを上書きしましたが、エラーは変わらず。

Answer (score 2):

Assets/Plugins/Android/　の中の　manifest.xml に
自分のパッケージ名を手書きで記載する必要がありました。